# How to check which map type is selected in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on a page. I need to check which map type the user has selected.

Can someone tell me how to perform this check?

```js
//set map options
var mapOptions = {
                center: newCenter,
                zoom: newZoom,
                styles: stylesArray,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
                }
            };

//create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

if (map.getCurrentMapType() == google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) {
  //set the current map type  
  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}
```

Comment: [map.getMapTypeId()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: map.getMapTypeId() always returns "roadmap" regardless of which map type I select.

Comment: I don't [see that behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/h7wsojox/1/).

Comment: You're right. There was another section of code being executed that I wasn't seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[map.getMapTypeId()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) returns the current mapTypeId.

```
document.getElementById('maptype').value=map.getMapTypeId();
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7wsojox/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
var mapOptions = {
  center: {
    lat: 45,
    lng: -112
  },
  zoom: 4,
  // styles: stylesArray,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
  }
};

//create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

if (map.getCurrentMapType() == google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP) {
  //set the current map type  
  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" value="get map type" onclick="document.getElementById('maptype').value=map.getMapTypeId();" />
<input type="text" value="" id="maptype" />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```